# Can I improve this water softener installation?

Tags: plumbing, water-softener

I recently DIY-installed this water softener in my home (see picture,) but I don't particularly like what I had to do to get it installed.

The 18" corrugated stainless bendy lines each have 1 inch FIP fittings at the softener ends, and 3/4 inch FIP fittings at the plumbing loop ends.  I don't particularly like how much I had to bend them to get them where they needed to go; they are almost kinked.  I also don't like how far from the wall the water softener has to sit in order to keep them from getting kinked.

I think perhaps if I ordered 15" replacement lines I wouldn't have to hairpin-bend them like this quite so badly, but I also think that would put stress on the plastic (CPVC) nipples on the water softener.

**UPDATE:** Another reason I don't like this, is that I intended to also install a particulate filter on the supply side.  But if I had, then I'd have needed to twist that corrugated line up like a crazy straw.

I am wondering if I could possibly redo this with some other combination of fittings and pex  (or any other recommendations that make sense.)

Also:  I didn't use thread dope on the CPVC fittings.  I didn't know if I should or not.  At the least, it is not leaking.

[image: My DIY softener installation]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Longer* flex lines, not shorter.

I have a very similar situation. I used braided lines rather than corrugated, but the bends are similar. In my case they protrude at a higher point. By using longer lines you can make more gradual bends at all points. Think spiral or loop rather than S-bend.

Alternatively, add onto the supply protrusions. Sweat new elbows or use Sharkbite fittings to raise the outputs and orient them so your flex lines can make a simple 90° or U-bends. S-bends are always more challenging.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why my searching didn't pull up braided lines. Possibly my search terms were biased by my prior experience of only seeing corrugated lines used.  I'll see if I can find some with the needed size fittings on the ends  (and also maybe add some elbows to the supply & return pipes.)

Comment: Never have I seen a more nicely decorated utility room! :) +1 on the _longer_ lines. My softener lines make a complete circle with braided lines and I haven't had a lick of trouble with them in the 10+ years this softener has been installed.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like you can add two 90 degree reducing elbows, 1" to 3/4" and short nipples, to the unit but you could do it to the supply side, 3/4" elbow and short nipple pointing up and drop down with the "bendy" lines. Just a thought.